# How to create instance of an ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net

From the code on one page I want to be able to generate an instance of another page and parse the html from certain controls on that page.

code which I used is:

```
var APIListPage = (APIList)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath
    ("~/APIHelp/APIList.aspx", typeof(APIList));

ParseHtml(APIListPage.pdfPage);
```

Comment: ... and what did/didn't happen? Please extend your question with details about what you want to do and what failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call the page instance's "ProcessRequest" procedure, to let it experience a full Page LifeCycle. It won't load just by creating the instance